# VS 2015 internal compiler error for static constexpr const char* a[] = {"foo", "bar"}

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-bug

this compiles fine:

```
static constexpr char* a[] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

this has an internal error (C1001) asking me to turn optimizations off, any ideas why?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C1001)&rd=true

```
static constexpr const char* a[]  = {"foo", "bar"};
```

this also compiles:

```
static constexpr const char* const a[] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

None of the two that compile have an array that's accessible via indexing.

Comment: *"internal compiler error"* means a bug in the compiler. If you have a workaround, use that while waiting for the next compiler service pack.

Comment: Just guessing here, but compiling with optimisations should logically be much harder to accomplish for the compiler than compiling without optimisations, so it's also more bug-prone.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to file a bug report.

Comment: I filed a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2471252

Comment: Wanted to Post an update that the bug on microsoft's end has been closed and marked fixed for vs2015 update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to come up with a work around until microsoft fixes the bug. It looks like there are a few issues with Constexpr expected to be fixed in VS 2015 update 2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/constexpr-in-vs2015-update-1/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/01/visual-studio-2015-update-1-is-here/#comments